# memory error with EigenAllocator

Tags: c++

When I training my model, it has no error. But when the code switches from one epoch to another epoch, it report the following error

> E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:244] tried to allocate 0 bytes
>   W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/allocator_retry.cc:32] Request to allocate 0 bytes
>   F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:104] EigenAllocator for GPU ran out of memory when allocating 0. See error logs for more detailed info.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please provide some code, what you have tried and where you have failed, thank you!